# how to count button press time in android?

Tags: java, android, timer

I am Developing an project in which i want diffrent task for diffrent time like if user button up after 5 milisecond then a code execute and if pressing time is more then that then a diffrent

actually em creating a chathead like in facebook chat

problem is this on ActionDown Event i want to open or launch my app

but problem is when user try to reallocate the chathead from one location to other the event fire
like

```
 This is my code
```

here in ACTION_DOWN event i want to intent to the app

```
      public class ChadHead extends Service {
  private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable mTimer1;
private WindowManager windowManager;
private ImageView chatHead;
Display display;
int width;
    int count=0;


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // Not used
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

     mTimer1 = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                count++;
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
                if (count == 1) {
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTimer1);
                    // put your code here:
                }
            }
        };



    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    chatHead = new ImageView(this);
    chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;

    windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);

    chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private int initialX;
        private int initialY;
        private float initialTouchX;
        private float initialTouchY;

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                initialX = params.x;
                initialY = params.y;
                initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                initialTouchY = event.getRawY();

                 mHandler.postDelayed(mTimer1, 0);
                /*Intent i;
                PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
                try {
                   i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.technorapper.technorappermapp");
                if (i == null)
                    throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                startActivity(i);
                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

                }*/


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TechnoRapper", 50)
                        .show();

                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                params.x = initialX
                        + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                params.y = initialY
                        + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, params);

                display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
                width = display.getWidth();

                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                 count = 0;
                if (initialTouchX < width / 2) {
                    initialTouchX = 0;
                } else if (initialTouchX >= width / 2) {
                    initialTouchX = width;
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (chatHead != null)
        windowManager.removeView(chatHead);
}
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced it since 3 month ago, here is my solution:

```
 private int count = 0;
    Button btn;
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Runnable mTimer1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        mTimer1 = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                count++;
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
                if (count == 1) {
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTimer1);
                    // put your code here:
                Intent i;
                PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
                try {
                   i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.technorapper.technorappermapp");
                if (i == null)
                    throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                startActivity(i);
                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

                }

                }
            }
        };
        btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, final MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    initialX = (int) btn.getX();
                    initialY = (int) btn.getY();
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                    initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mTimer1, 0);
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    count = 0;
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            btn.setX(initialX
                                    + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX));
                            btn.setY(initialY
                                    + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY));
                        }
                    });

                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

with this code you can move your chathead and the event start after 500 milisecond. No need to use OnClickListener, check if position not change so detect it as OnClickListener.
 And if you want to stop OnTouch event when catch some action, just put 'boolean variable' in ACTION_MOVE

Comment: hmm, I think this ok. Try to put your intent after mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTimer1)...  (like my update answer) then run for test. I am waiting for your answer

Comment: done but with some different trick but your ans helps me lot for that

thankyou

Comment: :D.Nice to meet you, let try together in adnroid

Answer (score 2):

You can use [View.OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) and two timestamp to store the button click start (ACTION_DOWN) and end time (ACTION_UP). Then, difference between this 2 variables (end-start) will tell you the duration of button click time and you can execute code according to your preference.

```
test.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    private long start = 0;
    private long end = 0;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            this.start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else if (event.getaction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            this.end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want do have custom durations you have to program it by yourself.

However it is recommended to use the android build in functions.
There are a [View.OnLongClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html) and a [View.OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) to distinguish from two different durations for clicking on views.

Comment: Actually em doing it in onTouchListner so any long-touch function is there or not

Answer (score 0):

i can't tell you the full exact code but i can explain the flow here, what i get from your answer is that you need to do different actions on the basis of last time the button is pressed, this is how you can do. You need two Date variables i.e. current and lastTime

```
  DateTimeUtils.getCurrentUTCFormattedDateTime()
```

store the lastTime in preferences on action down fetch the last time from preferences and get the current time and subtract it, to get the difference.

```
  long difference = (current.getTime() - lastSaved.getTime()) / 1000;
```

give you time difference in seconds, then you decide what to do. Hope it help :)

Comment: you may ask more if you need further guidance

Comment: actually em creating a chathead like in facebook chat 

problem is this on ActionDown Event i want to open or launch my app 

but problem is when user try to reallocate the chathead from one location to other the event fire

Comment: ok, but see no one can write full code for you, i have given you the idea as per my understanding, best of luck